# Which hook is the "undo" link, which is displayed when a product is removed from the cart, attached to?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to run a function when a removed product is reinserted into the cart. The link i am talking about is shown once a product is removed from the cart.
Below is the html of the link i am talking about.

```
<a href="http://localhost/cart/?undo_item=16bb1547e9801c1f69a8541378298b4c&amp;_wpnonce=a79dd8705c" class="restore-item">Undo?</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Which hook is the “undo” link, which is displayed when a product is removed from the cart, attached to?

The [`woocommerce_get_undo_url`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_get_cart_undo_url.html#3591) filter.

Specifically, the [`get_undo_url()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Cart.html#844-854) method of [`WC_Cart`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Cart.html), invokes [`wc_get_cart_undo_url()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-wc_get_cart_undo_url.html) which contains the [`woocommerce_get_undo_url`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_get_cart_undo_url.html#3591) hook.